# Equilateral partition

Tags: combinatorics

Let $\mathcal P_k(n)$ be the set of all subsets of $\{1, \dots, n\}$ that have cardinality $k$. Let $P$ be a partition of $\mathcal P_k(n)$. I say $P$ is equilateral if for every $X,Y \in P$, if $X \neq Y$ then there exists an integer $n_{X,Y}$ such that for all $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$, we have $|x \cap y|=n_{X,Y}$ (independently of the choice of $x$ and $y$).

I am looking for information about such partitions, in particular how many parts can they countain, and what can be the cardinalities of those parts?